# how to fix the php login which get user data from database code?

Tags: php, html

i give up, this php code still have problem. I will get email in password in database.
can you solve this? please help me

`$password = "";
        $email = "";
        $valid = 0;

```
    if (isset($_POST['email'])){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['password'])){
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    }

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","", "user");

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email,password FROM user");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed: ". mysqli_connect_error();
    }


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        if ($row[3] == $email && $row[5] == $password){
            $valid =  1;
            if(isset($_POST['remember'])){
                setcookie('Home', "true", time()+(30*86400));
            }
        }
    }
        if ($valid != 1){
             echo "<script>window.alert('email atau password salah!')</script>";
         }else {
            echo "<script>window.alert(\"Login success!\")</script>";
             //header('Location:Home.html');
         }




    mysqli_close($con);
?>`
```

Comment: we also give up if you don't share your code here

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: We cannot "solve this" based on the information you've given us.

Comment: **Post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: sorry im newbie and im forget to post the code

Answer (score 1):

Based on "*I will get email in password in database*" it sounds like `mysqli_fetch_row` is returning email as the 6th element in the result row (i.e. `$row[5]`).

First things first:  it is very important to heed the advice of @Jay Blanchard "***Never store plain text passwords!***" It is straightforward to implement [`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) when inserting the record and [`password_verify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) when retrieving it.

Have you considered using [`mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)? That will return an associative array, so columns can be accessed by name instead of relative order.

An example if clause would be:
 `if ($row['email'] == $email && password_verify($password, $row['password']))`

Much easier for the humans.

Comment: i want to use mysqli_fetch_row but why?

Comment: @CynthiaCaroline because that will return an associative array, so columns can be accessed by name instead of relative order.